# Need help with the following theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Theorem 4-5. If p is prime and d divides p-1, then there are exactly d roots of the congruence

$$x^d \equiv 1(mod\text{ } p)$$

Proof: Since $d|(p-1)$, we have

$$x^{p-1}-1 \equiv (x^d-1)q(x)$$

where $q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $p-1-d$ in x. By lagrange's theorem, the congruence

$$q(x) \equiv 0(mod\text{ } p)$$

has at most $p-1-d$ solutions. Since $x^{p-1} \equiv 1(mod\text{ } p)$ has exactly p-1 solutions, $x^d \equiv 1(mod\text{ } p)$ must have at least

$$p-1-(p-1-d)=d$$

solutions. Since it can have no more than this number, it must have exactly d solutions

The first thing that I would like to understand is why $x^{p-1}-1=(x^d-1)q(x)$

Comment: If we put $y=x^{d}$, then $x^{p-1}-1=y^{(p-1)/d}-1=(y-1)(y^{(p-1)/d-1}+\cdots+1)=(x^{d}-1)q(x)$ where $q(x)=x^{p-1-d}+x^{p-1-2d}+\cdots+1$.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque . Why is the following true $p-1-(p-1-d)=d$?

Comment: @TheMathNoob The idea is simple: if $\, f = gh\,$ and $\,f\,$ has $\,\deg f\,$ roots, then also $\,g\,$ has $\,\deg g\,$ roots and $\,h\,$ has $\,\deg h\,$ roots, since if one of $\,g,h\,$ had less, then the other would have to have more, contra Lagrange.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque. How does the factorization show that that the roots of $x^{p-1}-1$ are either roots of $x^d-1$ or roots of q(x)?

Comment: $0 \equiv f(n)\equiv g(n)h(n)\,\Rightarrow\, g(n)\equiv 0\,$ or $\,h(n)\equiv 0\,$ since $\,\Bbb Z/p\,$ is a domain; or, equivalently, $\,p\mid g(n)h(n)\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid g(n)\,$ or $\,p\mid h(n).\ $

Comment: The key point here is $Z/p$. What does that represent? We know that the roots are 1,2,....,p-1. How do we know that for example p-3 will be a root of  one polynomial but not of the other?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x^d=y.$ Since $d|(p-1)$ we have $p-1=dk$ with $k\in N.$ So $$x^{p-1}-1=x^{dk}-1=y^k-1=(y-1)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}y^j=(x^d-1)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}x^{dj}.$$

Comment: thanks now why does $x^{p-1} \equiv 1(mod \text{ } p)$ have p-1 roots by fermat's little theorem?

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem  (which is a special case of Lagrange's Theorem ) is that  $x^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ when $x\not \equiv 0 \pmod p.$ So the members of  $ \{j:1\leq j\leq p-1\} $ are  all solutions of $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ and they are all distinct,  $\pmod p.$

Comment: Can you provide a link to see the proof?

Comment: Since it is endemic, any text on introduction to number theory ought to have it. The wikipedia article Proofs Of Fermat's Little Therorem has many. but most of them look obscure and difficult, except for Euler's first proof, by induction on x, that (equivalently) $x^p\equiv x\pmod p$ for all $x$: In the (binomial theorem) expansion of $(x+1)^p$ all the terms except the first and last are divisible by $p$, since for $0<j<p$ the co-efficient $\binom {p}{j}=$ $p\cdot (p-1)!/j!(p-j)!$ and no  combination of terms in the denominator can cancel the "$p$" in the numerator (because $p$ is prime).

Comment: Fermat's little theorem is a special case of Lagrange's theorem that the number $|H|$ ,of members  of a subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G,$ divides $|G|.$   Now multiplication mod $p$ on $G=\{1,...,p-1\}$ is a finite group with $|G|=p-1 $.  For  any $0<x<p$ the smallest subgroup  containing $x$ has $d$ members, where $d$ is the least $n\in N$ such that $x^d\equiv 1\pmod p.$ Since $d|(p-1)$ we have therefore $x^{p-1}\equiv 1.$ Note: The set of remainders mod $p$ of  $\{x^n:n\in N\}$ is finite so for some $n,d\in N$ we have $x^n\equiv x^{n+d},$ so $d$ exists.

Comment: I am confused about the following claim: $p-1-(p-1-d)=d$ Why is that true ?because it's like the same way to find the degree of a polynomial, but I don't see how it would be true to count the number of roots

Comment: @TheMathNoob . i don't understand your last comment.

Comment: $x^{p-1} \equiv 1(mod \text{ } p)$ has exactly p-1 roots by fermat's theorem. $q(x) \equiv 0(mod \text{ } m)$ has  at most p-1-d solutions. How is it possible $x^d \equiv 1(mod \text{ } p)$ has at least $p-1-(p-1-d)=d$ solutions?

Comment: @TheMathNoob. That is another matter : The group $G= \{1,...,p-1\}$ with multiplication mod $p$ is a cyclic group. (This is NOT immediate from Fermat's little theorem.) So $G=\{y^j:  1\leq j\leq p-1\}$ for some $y\in G.$ (And for such $y,$ the least $n\in N$ for which $y^n\equiv 1$ is $n=p-1.$) For $d\in N$ and $d|(p-1)$ the solutions in $G$ of $x^d\equiv 1$ are the members of $\{y ^{j(p-1)/d} : 1\leq j\leq d\}.$ And there are $d$ solutions because $y^a\not \equiv y^b$ when $1\leq a<b\leq p-1.$